# SQL UPDATE multiple rows for different IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two tables that store the same data but have different `ID`s

Table 1:

| ID | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Foo |
| 20 | Mary | Bar |

Table: 2

| ID | name | address | OLD_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | John | Foo |  |
| 23 | Mary | Bar |  |

I'd like to update table 2 by inserting `ID`s from table 1 into `OLD_ID` column name and address match.

| ID | name | address | OLD_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | John | Foo | 1 |
| 23 | Mary | Bar | 20 |

I can do some horrible monstrosity that involves looping over each row in the second table, but I think there might be a way to do this using some CTE query magic.

Comment: Yes, you can do this in a single relatively easy to write statement. *However*.... you need to make sure there is a possible join between the 2 tables. John at Foo might not be unique enough, there could be many Johns and more than one of those Johns might live at Foo.

Comment: @milosgajdos did you try anything writing and facing any issue?

Comment: @donstack yes I have a FOR LOOP SQL statement which is very slow over the size of the table I want to do this on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple query. You just need update `table2.old_id` by setting it values from `table1.id` for rows where their `name` and `address` values are equal.

```
UPDATE table2 SET old_id = (
    SELECT id FROM table1 
    WHERE table1.name = table2.name AND table1.address = table2.address
)
```